# Docker - how to edit yml file after pull

Tags: docker, docker-compose, yaml, pull

Docker pull allows to pull directly ie. weblate/weblate

fine, but it is neccessary to create a docker-compose.overwrite.yml file with config to run

so, the question is: where to place that file, how to handle that topic? cannot find the location for that yml file (there should be also a docker-compose.yml file available)

additional information:
if done via cloning the weblate-docker repo, it is possible to add that file, but, is it also possible to do it when "just" pulling?

Comment: Docker images does not container files sich as docker-compose.yml.

Comment: what would be the approach then to have that easy pull, but, still be able to add yml file to be used?